# Issue with two UITableViews in single UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've seen similar questions, but none with the same issue.

In a UIViewController I have two UITableViews tableView1 and tableView2 (which is within a UIScrollView). The datasource and delegate on both tables are set to the UIViewController, which implements UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource protocols. The UIViewController is itself within a UITabBarController as follows:

- UITabBarController

  - UIViewController

    - UITableView (tableView1)
    - UIScrollView

      - UITableView (tableView2)

Within the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I check which table and populate accordingly:

```
if (tableView == _tableView1) {
    //do stuff for tableView1
} else {
    //do stuff for tableView2
}
```

When the UIViewController appears only tableView1 is populated with data. Tapping on another tab and then back again finally populates tableView2.

If tableView1's delegate and datasource are set to nil, tableView2 never gets populated. It appears that tableView2 only gets populated once tableView1 has been populated.

Can anyone help with this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you doing the same check in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and  `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`?

Comment: have you tired this?
if (tableView == _tableView1) {
    //do stuff for tableView1
}if (tableView == _tableView2) {
    //do stuff for tableView2
}

Comment: Table view inside scroll view next to another table view? I for one don't want to use that UI...

Comment: @jonkroll yes, doing the same in those methods. Thanks.

Comment: @pKoul thanks, yeah, tried that too

Comment: @jrtc27 useful comment. it's to implement a tv guide style grid. one table view to list channels and the other in a scrollview showing the programmes.

Comment: OK, so in my question I state the iVars were _tableView1 and _tableView2. These were actually _indexTableView and _tableView. Changing _tableView to _gridTableView seems to have solved this issue.

Can't close this question until the 8 hours is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I state the iVars were `_tableView1` and `_tableView2`. These were actually `_indexTableView` and `_tableView`. Changing `_tableView` to `_gridTableView` seems to have solved this issue.